# Why non-daemon thread is terminated then all SWT GUI threads are closed on Windows?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, multithreading, swt

I open the main window using SWT then application starts, and then the window runs task non-daemon thread via static function. Now, then window is closed, entire application is terminated, killing the task thread in unknown condition. It's something happens on windows, while running on Linux, the thread keeps running in background, checks the custom semaphore and terminates correctly.
Is there a reason and/or a workaround to reach the same behavior on Windows platform?

Giving a-weird-looking example of code:

```
    package kg.clockworker;

    public class Storage implements Runnable{
        static int clockValue = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(clockValue=0; clockValue<1000; clockValue++)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ClockWorker.main(null);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Storage());
        //t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

    }

}

    package kg.clockworker;

    import org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext;
    import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm;
    import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.SWTObservables;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ClockWorker extends Shell {

    private Label label;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Realm.runWithDefault(SWTObservables.getRealm(display), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Display display = Display.getDefault();
                    ClockWorker shell = new ClockWorker(display);
                    shell.open();
                    shell.layout();
                    display.timerExec(40, new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            shell.label.setText(Storage.clockValue+"");
                            display.timerExec(40, this);
                        }

                    });


                    Storage.main(null);

                    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                            display.sleep();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the shell.
     * @param display
     */
    public ClockWorker(Display display) {
        super(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.RESIZE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        label = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        label.setBounds(31, 20, 70, 20);
        label.setText("0");
        createContents();

    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the shell.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        setText("ClockWorker");
        setSize(407, 132);

    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
    }
    protected DataBindingContext initDataBindings() {
        DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
        //
        return bindingContext;
    }
}
```

On Linux: then ClockWorker is closed, application still running with Storage. Termination code may be implemented.
On Windows: then ClockWorker is closed, Storage is also down, possibly in unfinished condition.

Comment: share your code? Why do you think on Linux you have semaphore etc?

Comment: Have you tried using try/finally or runtime shutdown hooks? Have you tried adding it to the close listener?

Comment: The problem is not to close the thread manually, but it's automatic termination on windows then all GUI is closed. I want it in the Linux way: to close it manually on semaphore i.e. variable change, freeing resourses correctly, but it is down as all GUI closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what `Realm.runWithDefault()` does; it calls the `run()` method of your `Runnable`, synchronously, and when that `run()` returns, the calling code continues. The key is that you have the call to `Realm.runWithDefault()` in a main method, so when `runWithDefault()` returns it continues in your `main()` which ends and thus terminates your process.

In your `Runnable` you're executing the typical SWT event loop (`readAndDispatch()`) which keeps the `Runnable` going while the `Shell` is not disposed, but as soon as you close the `Shell` the SWT loop exits, which ends your `run()` method (which in turn returns control back to `main()` as described above).

I'm not sure why this would work differently on Linux because IIRC these rules are the same on any JVM. In any case, if you want your process to continue after the SWT shell has closed, you need to add some logic to do that; basically coordinate between the two threads you have.

Comment: The Realm.runWithDefault part is added later by Eclipse binding. Originally Storage main method was running from main method of main window directly.

Comment: It doesn't really matter; it behaves just as if the code in the `run()` method was directly in your `main()` method.